# User account is unaffected by AD name change

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

I renamed our AD domain and the NETBIOS name. The NETBIOS name in particular was changed from `FOO` to `CONTOSO`.

However, when I log into my workstation and open, for example, Remote Desktop Connection, it will offer to log onto remote machines as `FOO\Oliver`. This will fail.

Likewise, Server Manager is unable to remotely log onto servers in our network. Some research indicates that this is due to Server Manager using the wrong NETBIOS name to connect to the server.

I checked my user account in AD and the NETBIOS name for my account is correctly set to `CONTOSO`.

Why is my workstation still using the old name?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a chaching issue. To verify if it is, check the environment variable `USERDOMAIN`. If it still points to the old name, try this:

1. Completely log off from your workstation.
2. On the login screen, select **Other user**.
3. Enter your usual credentials.